# Connect react components with an SVG line

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to achieve this:
[image]

My api provides the id of the parent element in the upper level, all levels are located in the same React component (as of cards).

How can I connect the cards in different levels with SVG lines?

I thought I can get all coordinates of every card, then according to the relations I can create lines with starting point and ending point. But I don't know how to get them, In the parent component I should have refs for any Card component in order to use `getBoundingClientRect()` although I didn't find a way to store N refs in a functional component.

I'm also concerned about how to give the ankle curve to the connector. I'm currently using d3 for drawing lines.

current code:

```
<Row style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
  <Col span={8}>
    <strong>TOP LEVEL</strong>
    <Divider />
    {data.length ? data[0].map(item => <ProductCard item={item} key={item.product_offer_id} />) : []}
  </Col>
  <Col span={8}>
    <strong>SUB LEVEL 1</strong>
    <Divider />
    {data.length ? data[1].map(item => <ProductCard item={item} key={item.product_offer_id} />) : []}
  </Col>
  <Col span={8}>
    <strong>SUB LEVEL 2</strong>
    <Divider />
    {data.length ? data[2].map(item => <ProductCard item={item} key={item.product_offer_id} />) : []}
  </Col>
  <svg id="svg1" style={{ margin: '0 auto', display: 'block', position: 'absolute' }}></svg>
</Row>
```

Comment: Can you use react components inside SVG? In that case, please provide a [mre] of your code so it's easier to see what you mean

Comment: If you don't want to use dj3, this lib [react-svg-connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-connector) can help you easily achieve it.